# Edge collider does not cover the entire sprite shape in unity. What should I do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a sprite shape as you can see in the screen shots that I have attached along with my question. The green line you see is called edge collider. Right now it is in the meddle of the sprite. If I change the offset in sprite shape controller component it can either detect the collision on the top or bottom of the sprite. But I want it to detect the collision on both side of the sprite.
I have watched a tutorial on youtube and it works fine in the video. Here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSo_fU1JdfM  and the timestamp is 5:04

[when offset is zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43MN4.jpg)

[when offset is -0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYDRt.jpg)

[when offset is 0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD4EF.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how can I provide code when I have not used any? I just hit the play but and toss a ball from a hight that has 2d circle collider and rigidbody. if I set the offset 0.5. Sprite will detect the collision with ball but if ball is below the sprite  and jump then collision will be detected but ball overlap some part of the sprite. Did you see those screenshots that I attached.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old tutorial. You're using a more modern version of Unity. What you want to do is change the **Edge Radius** of the **Edge Collider** to make the collider thicker, like in the tutorial.